# Android WebView and html5 vids

Tags: java, android, webview, xamarin

Please, is there any way to force WebView to play html5 embedded vids? I spent two days tempting it (from just enabling js and plugins with hardware acceleration to using html5webview class) and made video tag working, but embedding with iframe only shows me preview. 
Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Does it play if you click on it manually? There are all sorts of things that may go wrong with HTML5 video on the internet, on Android you also have to take into account the various permissions.

Try this first:

1. Load the webpage in a browser - does it work?
2. Load the webpage in the browser on the device, does it work?
3. Load the webpage in the webview, does it play when you click on it?

There should be an auto play property on the webview, but I know that one IOS at least that one is ignore and the video won't play until you click it.

Comment: I know about autoplay disabled. On manual click video just disappears - white rectangle and no internet activity. Webpage works with Dolphin browser, which is using WebKit too, and in desktop browser as well.